# Don't have desktop icons lock to grid

Tags: display, icons, xfce, mythbuntu, desktop-icons

I am building a Mythbuntu media center, the display being a 42" television. I set the text and desktop icons to be extremely large so they are readable from the couch. This is good, but all of the icons align to the top of the screen, and because the icon size is so large  I can't have them move down one position. I am a perfectionist a this bothers me. Does anyone know how to tell XFCE to not snap desktop icons to a grid? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click desktop, uncheck 'Keep Alligned'.