# Why Desktop, Icons are overflown by other icons, and how to fix it?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

Why Ubuntu does that, it is so inefficient to work, when files can be aligned like that. If one more user will try to mention that this is "a feature of Ubuntu, GNOME, Nautilus", I'm seriously doubting if anything is good of Ubuntu or any desktop Linux distribution, as these kind of features do not have any positive impact on any kind of work.

[image: example of a Linux desktop icons failure]

Comment: If you're asking for help, please edit your question to make that clear. Otherwise, your question may be closed as unclear.

Comment: @DKBose
Edited. It is just frustrating to find any proper documentation,  coverage on basic functions that are inside Ubuntu, i'm really giving up on linux distributions, they are unfriendly and functionless for standard work, with worst programming practices. It is suprising that anything works at all.

Even terminal commands are named after abbreviations of custom project name, rather than simplified function work.

Comment: Just a pointer, GNOME has [decided to get rid of desktop icons](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/gnome-desktop-icons-removed-3-28) altogether from v3.28. Also "*they are unfriendly and functionless for standard work, with worst programming practices*" - I reckon that's going to be a pretty unpopular opinion.

Comment: Seems to have been reported previously: https://askubuntu.com/questions/471502/stop-avoid-overlapping-desktop-icons

Comment: @pomsky some opinions here: https://community.ubuntu.com/t/files-nautilus-v3-28-will-lose-the-desktop-icons-capability/3115

Comment: Even Linus Torvalds is using mailing lists rather than use github  for managing and approving suggested works. The reason is simple: github is not made for scaling up.  It is actually horrible how uncomplete everything is, and how much work is needed right now to do simple productive work on a linux distribution. #RagingOnEveryonesIncompetence

Now they have deep problems with desktop icons, so they propose solutions like: let'us just remove it, instead of fixing it.

Comment: I'm not even sure what deep problem is, isn't linux suppose to be as moddable as possible. I heard a lot back in days, from those pesky nerdy programmers that with linux distributions changes are easy and simple.

Comment: Could anyone point me to the most relevant active forum/site/platform, where I could share my frustration with linux distributions. #LotsOfRage

Comment: @pomsky, that's what I understand from https://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2018/01/09/%23ubuntu-desktop.html?_ga=2.50429929.1139788881.1511369400-1599365810.1511369400#t14:55

Comment: Yeah, we get it, you have *#LotsOfRage* and you're *#RagingOnEveryonesIncompetence*, but please understand this is not the right place for raging. It's a Q&A site (*not* like other forums) with the contribution from a user-community. We're *not* official designers/developers.

Comment: @pomsky, well should I make another question and ask "Which is the most active and impactful Linux/Ubuntu/Debian forum/platform you know?"

Comment: @user3789797 Then I think it'll be closed at Ask Ubuntu as off-topic. You may post at our sister-site https://unix.stackexchange.com/, but there I reckon it'll be closed as "primarily opinion based" or "off-topic".

Comment: @pomsky Well most problem solving related questions has opinionated answers.
That's why Stack platforms has these rating arrows next to an answer, there is not  a single way to solve a problem or answer a question. It is hard for me to believe that these type of questions could be closed and are unwelcomed in the unix stackexchange.

Comment: @user3789797 Yeah, but asking for suggestion for another *Linux/Ubuntu/Debian forum/platform* is just not on-topic here or there.

Comment: @pomsky Where is a place for this kind of topic on the internet. I really need/want to know that. You seem to be not that new in this whole  linux subject, as I am, just direct me and i'll delete the comments unrelated to  this question.

Comment: Try https://ubuntuforums.org/ or reddit for (possibly opinion-based) discussions. Just to be clear, the core of your question ("how do I fix desktop icon overlapping issue?") *is* on-topic here. Take a [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) of the site and read [this](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) & [this](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) for details.

Comment: Thank you @pomsky, going on the search in the Reddit. 
I'll keep an eye on this question, as i'm still looking for the solution to this whole desktop icons thing that seems to happens for years now on different desktop and file management systems for different reasons mainly on Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't have desktop icons lock to grid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118051/dont-have-desktop-icons-lock-to-grid)